# Stuck in trying to find integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the integral of

$$
\int\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)^3}dx
$$

yet I've been stuck on this section for a long time, the integral calculator I'm using does not help me understand the process of determining the integral.

Any advice/assistance is happily accepted and appriciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I would try $x=a\sin(\theta)$ for starters. I removed an extraneous right paren; make sure it reads as you intended.

Comment: It would be better to include some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960); for example, what section of what book or what course you are studying (so we know what you can use), what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we substitute
$$ x = a \sin{u}, \text{  } dx = a\cos{u}$$
Then $(a^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}=(a^2-a^2\sin^2{u})^\frac{3}{2} = a^3\cos^3{u}$ and $u=\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$, so our integral is equal to:
$$a^4\int \cos^4(u) du$$
Using the [integral reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) we obtain that
$$a^4\int cos^4(u)du = \frac{a^4}{4}\sin{u}\cos^3{u}+\frac{3a^4}{4}\int \cos^2(u)du$$

Using the formula again:
$$\int \cos^2(u)du = \frac{1}{2}(u + \cos{u}\sin{u})$$
So our whole integral is equal to:
$$\frac{a^4}{4}\sin{u}\cos^3{u}+\frac{3a^4}{8}(u + \cos{u}\sin{u})$$

We substitute back $u=\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$ to obtain:
$$\frac{a^4}{4}\sin({\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})})\cos^3{(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))}+\frac{3a^4}{8}(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}) + \cos{(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))}\sin{(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})}))$$
$$\frac{a^3x}{4}\cos^3{(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))}+\frac{3a^4}{8}(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}) + \cos{(\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))}\frac{x}{a})$$
We may use that $\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to simplify further.

Comment: This question is a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854). Once you give a full answer, there is no incentive for the OP to improve the question.

Comment: The information supplied here assisted me in understanding the solution, no matter if a full answer was given or merely a clue.

Comment: @Aishgadol if this is the case, please consider upvoting or accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\text{Let }x&=a\sin{\theta}\\
\implies dx&=a\cos{\theta}\;d\theta\\
\int\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)^3}\;dx&=\int\sqrt{a^6\cos^6{\theta}}.a\cos{\theta}\;d\theta\\
&=a^4\int\cos^4{\theta}\;d\theta
\end{align}
I am not going to give the whole solution. From here, you can try reducing the power of $\cos^4{\theta}$ by using:
\begin{align}
2\cos^2{\theta}=1+\cos{2\theta}\\
2\sin^2{\theta}=1-\cos{2\theta}
\end{align}

Comment: This question is a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854). Once you give a full answer, there is no incentive for the OP to improve the question.